Vertical edges appear shaky while the camera moves horizontally
I have noticed that in the video



the vertical edges of the rock (I mean the rock that is a kind of a monument just behind the subject) seem to jump back and forth while the camera is steadily panning left.
This phenomenon is particularly noticeable when the playback speed is set to 0.5.
The author of the video says it was shot with a gimbal, but I’m unsure if this particular part was as well.
What could be causing this issue?
